# Core Data: NSPredicate containing to-many relationship yields no results when using SQLITE store type

Tags: ios, core-data, many-to-many, nspredicate

I have been using Core Data with In-Memory store for my project until recently. Now I am trying to switch to SQLite store and I'm facing the following issue:

When Trying to fetch objects from the store using a predicate and sortDescriptor, my  fetchedResultsController returns 0 objects. The exact same code works fine when the store type is in-memory.

This is how I am making the fetch:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY %K == %@", @"categories", category];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
self.fetchedResultsController = [self createFetchedResultsControllerWithEntityName : @"Provider" sectionName : @"group" sortDescriptor : sortDescriptor predicate : predicate cache : nil];

NSError *error = nil;
if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}       

[self.tableView reloadData];
```

and this is where I create the fetch request:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)createFetchedResultsControllerWithEntityName : (NSString*) entityName sectionName : (NSString*) sectionName sortDescriptor : (NSSortDescriptor*) sortDescriptor predicate : (NSPredicate*) predicate cache : (NSString*) cacheName{ 

// Create the fetch request for the entity.
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
// Edit the entity name as appropriate.
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

//set predicate 
if (predicate)
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate]; 

// Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
// nil for section name key path means "no sections".
NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest 
                                                                                                managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext 
                                                                                              sectionNameKeyPath:sectionName 
                                                                                                       cacheName:cacheName];
aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

[fetchRequest release];
[sortDescriptor release];
[sortDescriptors release];


return [aFetchedResultsController autorelease];
```

}

Again, this very same code fetches many objects when using in-memory store, but an empty fetchedObjects array when using SQLite.

I've read Apple's documentation with regard to the special considerations to make when using predicates and sortDescritors with SQLite store. I am using a single (many-)to-many relationship (categories) in the predicate, so this should be fine?

There is no error returned from the fetch. Simply no objects (fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects is empty).

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've figured out this issue eventually.

My query returned no results there were indeed no results. Tracing this back to where I was creating the objects and populating the realtionships with values I noticed that I was doing it wrong. I tried to do:

```
[provider.categories addObject : newCategory];
```

Which did not really add newCategory to the categories relationship.
After having realized that Core Data generates the accessors for to-many relationships automatically, I used the following to add newCategory:

```
[provider addCategoriesObject : newCategory];
```

This properly added newCategory to the relationship.

In addition to that I declared addCategoriesObject in Provider.h to suppress the compiler warning. This resolved the issue for me.

The only remaining caveat is that the compiler does not find the implementation of addCategoriesObject: and warns about "incomplete implementation". I haven't figured out a way to suppress this warning too.

Answer (score 0):

I know SQLite stores have problems with `"ANY"` fetches in some cases (I don't remember the exact ones). Maybe try modifying your search predicate to see if you get different results, e.g.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"categories LIKE %@", category];
```